# Change Bootstrap 3 Navbar from transparent to not transparent when in mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, transparency, navbar

I have a transparent Navbar in Bootstrap 3, and am trying to get the navbar to no longer be transparent if on a mobile device.  In other words, if you expand the menu on a mobile device, I would like the menu items to have a non-transparent colored background.

Haven't been able to figure out how to do this - any ideas?

My HTML code is below:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-absolute navbar-transparent big" role="navigation" id="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Head -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img src="assets/images/logo_big.png" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Items -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                    <!-- Left -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog/">BLOG</a></li>
                        <li><a href="price/">PRICING</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your own media queries like this for mobile devices

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-transparent {
        background: #000 !important; /*Add your own background*/
    }
}
```

The demo is [here](http://www.bootply.com/yH2T7AEHNj)